# How to implement the Kendo Progress bar for jQuery Ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

My requirement is to show the kendo progress bar when ever the jQuery Ajax call is intiating and then once i got the response 
i need to close the progress. The response may be success or error but for both the case i need to close the progress bar.

Please provide any example for this.

Thanks in adavnce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the below code , Before Calling the `ajax` start the progress bar and stop the progress bar in `ajax complete` as it will run irrespective of response come as `success` or `error`.

```
  function StartProgessBar() {
        kendo.ui.progress($("#progessbardiv"), true); //Here progess bar will intiate
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              //no need to close the progess bar here as we have handling it in complete
            },
            error: function () {
                ////nor need to close the progess bar here as we have handling it in complete
            },
            complete: function () {
                kendo.ui.progress($("#progessbardiv"), false); //close the progress bar
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. is it possible to give any working examples using above code?

Comment: @bagya check this http://fiddle.jshell.net/qy6sgmpq/14/ . remove `setTimeout` from your actual code

Comment: Please look this fiddle. It's not working in real code. http://fiddle.jshell.net/5s9box71/1/. can you please advice on this.

Comment: @bagya the `url` `file.fileUrl` is incorrect.You can see the error in chrome console.

Comment: File.fileurl it's a server side url. It's not a problem.   Progress bar not initiating. While running my application. If I set the timeout then it's coming. I would request to you please give solution without timeout function if you want use url please use as per your wish.

Comment: @bagya is the progess bar is not initiating ?

Comment: ..Yes and it should wait to complete the call (http call)

Comment: what ever code is there fiddle. it won't wok in fiddle mode. because i just copy and pasted in fiddle for your reference. i  gave that fiddle link where i have to include my progress bar. it's in my real application code. It's requires service URL and security token and etc.. you just need to check or please change the code.

Comment: @bagya the link you have given the Progress bar is initiating. Then what is the issue.in the real scenarios it's not  initiating ?

Comment: ..yeah. it's not initiating. i think we have to take the length of call(http call) and then we need initiate the progress bar.

Comment: In debug mode it's initiating and not opening normal mode.

Comment: @bagya Put a delay using `setTimeout`

Comment: setTimeout  is predefined one but my requirement is time out should happen once that call completed. is there any other way to find the ajax call duration. if i find that duration then i will assign that duration value to setTimeOut or any other method related to delay. please give any other solution for this.